# Undoing a commit in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, undo

I committed a bunch of files (dozens of files in different folders) by accident. What is the easiest, cleanest (and safest!) way to 'undo' that commit without having to delete the files from my working directory?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Go to **Show Log** Screen, select the revision that you want to undo, right click it and select **Revert changes from this revision**, this will do a [reverse-merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo).

Comment: Thats what I was expecting but no sign in the latest tortoise release

Comment: Don't forget to commit afterwards, because it just merges locally.

Comment: Make sure to update your working copy before doing this, otherwise nothing happens.

Comment: Docs on this procedure: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html

Comment: TortoiseSVN > Show Log > <select your old revesion> > Revert to this revision
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html

Comment: @FlorianBrucker : Thanks for the note about svn update. svn log showed recent changes but file is not updated and revert was not working.

Comment: This doesn’t only undo the commit, because the files are in the state of the commit before and not before the commit.

Answer (score 15):

You may need to use the command line, but you can use the SVN merge command and specify the revisions in reverse to effectively revert a commit.  Assuming your bad commit was r1123, you would do:

```
svn merge -r1123:1122 <url of your working copy>
```

Comment: Nothing changes when I do like this:                                                       svn merge -r 1880:1879 https://server/myproject/branches/problem42                        I have tried both with space like this "-r 1880:1879" and without space like this "-r1880:1879". If I run "svn st" afterwards then nothing has changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can revert your working copy to the revision prior to the commit. Once you have reverted your working copy, then simply commit the changes and you will effectively rolled back the accidental commit.

In a case like yours specifically, I would probably check out the revision that I wanted to roll back into a new working copy and then commit the working copy to the head revision.

Comment: Would this not tell you that your revision is out of date and require you to update before you commit? I think you need to merge the prior revision rather than just update to the old one.

Comment: Also, this strategy assumes that the bad commit is the previous one. You may want to undo some changes which happened a while ago, without undoing all of them.