# Can I recover a branch after its deletion in SVN install on local server?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, git-svn

If I run svn branch -d XYZ, is there a way to recover the branch? Is there a way to go back as if I didn't run the delete branch command?

Comment: I try to resolve the issue using this thread but unable to get the output .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568484/need-to-restore-a-deleted-branch-in-subversion

Comment: What do you mean by "the output"?

Comment: Since your are using a version control system, you can always retrieve old information. So just checkout/export the revision before the deletion of the branch.