# SVN - delete a revision, or make an older revision the head

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm fairly new to SVN and I've never had to revert back to a previous revision, although I can get a copy of a revision from the repository okay.  I'm using TortoiseSVN and the Visual Studio SVN plugin.

I'd like to restore the trunk back to a previous revision.

How can I restore the trunk - e.g. rollback to a previous revision and make this the head?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN - How do I change the HEAD to a previous revision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339727/svn-how-do-i-change-the-head-to-a-previous-revision)

Comment: I think the question is slightly different - my question asks if it's possible to delete a revision - or if reverse merging is the only way

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you need is a so-called reverse merge:

```
svn merge -r HEAD:<rev_you_want_to_revert_to>
```

See the [Tortoise SVN merge documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html) for details on how to do that with Tortoise SVN. Also see [the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.branchmerge.commonuses.html#svn.branchmerge.commonuses.undo) (copied link from [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248821/undoing-a-commit-in-tortoisesvn); it's actually a FAQ).

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to do that with TortoiseSVN:

- show the log for the working copy (opens the log dialog)
- select the revision you want to undo or the revision to which you want to go back to
- right-click on that revision, then choose "revert item to this revision" or "revert changes from this revision".

The former of those two commands reverts the working copy to the state it was in that revision, while the latter only reverts the changes of that specific revision withour reverting later changes too.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common use for `svn merge`.
You need to specify a reverse difference (e.g. `--revision 303:302` or by an equivalent `--change -303`):

```
 svn merge -c -303 http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk
```

Comment: will this merge revision 303 into the specified trunk?

Comment: @freefallr: this will undo the change made by revision 303 in your working copy. After this you need to commit the rollback.