# SVN - make old revision the trunk

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have updated to a previous revision and now want to make this revision the new trunk.

No branches or tags - I simply want to replace the trunk with an old revision.

How is this best achieved

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN - delete a revision, or make an older revision the head](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879938/svn-delete-a-revision-or-make-an-older-revision-the-head)

Comment: You need to do down merging (merge the trunk with older revision which you want). That is simple and proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

svn merge the HEAD with the revision you want to revert to. 
[read this](http://ariejan.net/2007/03/27/subversion-how-to-revert-to-a-previous-revision/) or else just look at some of the many repeats of this FAQ in the 
"Related" list to the right -->